# Trouble receiving inputs from IOT hub Streaming Analytics Job

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm currently testing Tatsoft software for a new project. I followed their [MQTT and Azure IoT](https://docs.tatsoft.com/display/DOC91/MQTT+And+Azure+IoT) tutorial. Very simple, was able to send messages to the IoT Hub no problem. Now I'm stuck in Stream Analytics job.

"Unable to connect to input source at the moment. Please check if the input source is available and if it has not hit connection limits."

The test connection works and the event serialization format is correct (JSON). The analytics job does run.

[Error view in stream analytics job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxlWl.png)

Comment: Did you create a separate Consumer Group for your Stream Analytics job to connect with? Using $Default can have this result.

Comment: You should also try using VS Code and the ASA Tools extension instead. You can preview data from your source there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/visual-studio-code-local-run-live-input